# Loop performance with LINQ clause

Tags: c#, performance, loops, linq

is there any performance difference between both ?
In my opinion, the second method is slower because linq must re-execute the where clause to each iteration, is that right ?

Thanks :)

```
List<string> someObjects = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };

var filteredCollection = someObjects.Where(s => s.Contains('w'));

foreach (string str in filteredCollection)
{
    // some code
}
```

```
List<string> someObjects = new List<string>() { "one", "two" };

foreach (string str in someObjects.Where(s => s.Contains('w')))
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: No, they are the same. It is executed only once

Comment: The `Where` will only be evaluated once in both.

Comment: Well, the delegate passed to the Where-clause will be evaluated once **per list item** on both cases. And it will also start the evaluation in the foreach in both cases.

Comment: The `Where` creates a query that is executed only once in both approaches(at the `foreach`). It will be enumerated in a streaming manner. What you use simply depends on your personal preferences and if you want to reuse that query after the `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` is a bit of syntax sugar:

```
foreach(string str in someObjects.Where(s => s.Contains('w'))) 
{
   // some code (using str)
}
```

would be expanded by the compiler to something like

```
IEnumerator<string> iterator = someObjects.Where(s => s.Contains('w')).GetEnumerator();
while(iterator.MoveNext())
{
    // some code (using iterator.Current)
}
```

The `Where()` extension method is only called once at the beginning to create the iterator.